# What is the best way to connect an APM controller to ROS?

Tags: ros, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a few multicopters with an APM controller that I would like to connect to ROS. I want to access the mavlink data via ROS topics. Minimally, I want to have access to sensor data and then publish control topics to the UAV for some semi autonomous indoor fun.

I see there are a few options out there for packages, does anyone out there have recommendations or helpful hints to get started?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97131/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-an-apm-controller-to-ros?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-11-05**:
if you find something interesting, let me know, please. i would be very thankful for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at roscopter?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-11-06**:
This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. :) Thanks!

**Comment by [Dushan Eranga](https://answers.ros.org/users/29615/dushan-eranga/) on 2017-03-08**:
Is roscopter compatible with ros indigo ?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2017-03-08**:
Would strongly advice against that, use mavros.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try my project - mavros (github.com/vooon/mavros).
More needs to be done, but much has been done.

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-06-03**:
Hi @vooon. Trying to catkin_make my dir with mavros in src folder. Already have mavlink in mavros folder. Gives me:
File "../src/mavros/mavlink/pymavlink/generator/mavgen.py", line 14, in 
from pymavlink.generator import mavparse
ImportError: No module named pymavlink.generator
Any tip?

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2014-06-04**:\

1. Use wstool to install (it's automatically downloads all submodules)
2. Try to install pymavlink if error exists after 1.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look to this projects:

https://github.com/posilva/ardupilotmega-ros

https://github.com/posilva/mav2rosgenerator

hope that helps

pms

---

Originally posted by [pmosilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/19772/pmosilva/) with karma: 56 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You definitely want to try mavros. We are using it with Erle-Brain ( http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Erle-brain ) and so far we are really happy with it.

---

Originally posted by [v.mayoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/4008/v.mayoral/) with karma: 88 on 2015-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2